# Delete button not working after adding another entry to my Library object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dom

I have a problem that my delete button (the yellow one) works perfectly on preloaded book library items, but it isn't on the new entry when I add a book and want to delete it... I also want you to ask what it would be the easiest way to delete books also from myLibrary array... Thanks.

I've attached my code here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
//DOM
const bookForm = document.querySelector(".book-form");

// Calling a form when clicking on add book button
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
  console.log("dsafsa");
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}

// where the books will be saved...
let myLibrary = [{
    title: "Harry Potter - and the Philosopher's Stone",
    author: "J. K. Rowling",
    pages: 223,
    readStatus: "no",
  },
  {
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "J.R.R. Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
    readStatus: "yes",
  },
];

// book object
function Book(title, author, pages, readStatus) {
  (this.title = title),
  (this.author = author),
  (this.pages = pages),
  (this.readStatus = readStatus);
}

let i = "";
// render the book on page load...
function render() {
  const books = myLibrary;
  books.forEach((book) => {
    addNewBookUI(book);
  });
}
render();

document.querySelector(".book-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  // prevent actual submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // get values
  const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  const author = document.querySelector("#author").value;
  const pages = document.querySelector("#pages").value;
  const readStatus = document.querySelector('input[name="yes_no"]:checked')
    .value;
  // prevent empty fields ...

  if (title === "" || author === "" || pages === "0") {
    alert("Missing data");
  } else {
    const book = new Book(title, author, pages, readStatus);
    myLibrary.push(book);
    addNewBookUI(book);
    clearFormFields()
  }
});

function addNewBookUI(book) {
  if (book.readStatus === "yes") {
    i = "checked";
  } else {
    i = "";
  }
  const main = document.querySelector(".main");
  const bookCard = document.createElement("div");
  bookCard.classList.add("book-card");
  bookCard.innerHTML = `<div class="delete_button"><button class="delete btn"><i class="fa fa-trash">
        </i></button></div><div class="title">${book.title}</div><div class="author">${book.author}
        </div><div class="pages">${book.pages}</div><div class="read_status">Read: <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="readstatus" value="yes" ${i}> 
        </div>`;
  main.appendChild(bookCard);
}

// clear form fields after submit 
function clearFormFields() {
  const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
  myForm.reset();
}

// Add event listener to all deleteButton 
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");

// deletes book UI;
deleteButton.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    el.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    console.log("sas")
  })
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #155999;
  border-bottom: #172f4f solid 10px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

header button {
  background-color: #183153;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plus-sign {
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #183153;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.book-card {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 1000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #155999;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: #172f4f solid 8px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  box-shadow: 10px 4px 22px -5px rgba(21, 89, 153, 1);
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(21, 89, 153);
  background-color: rgba(21, 89, 153, 0.7);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #c3c6d1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

.book-card div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/* Style buttons */

.btn {
  background-color: #ffd43b;
  /* Blue background */
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
  color: red;
  /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Mouse pointer on hover */
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -15px;
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #183153;
}

.delete_button {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

form div {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radiobutton {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-flex input {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px
}

.form-flex input::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #183153;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radiobutton p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.flexbuttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- The overlay -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form  id="myForm" class="book-form">
      <div class="form-flex">
        <label for="title">Book name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Book name...">
      </div>
      <div class="form-flex">
        <label for="author">Book author:</label>
        <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Book author...">
      </div >
      <div class="form-flex">
        <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
        <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="0" name="pages">
      </div>
      <div class="radiobutton">
        <p>Have you read a book?</p>
        <div class="flexbuttons">
          <div>
            <p><input type="radio" id="huey" name="yes_no" value="yes" checked>
              <label for="huey">yes</label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p><input type="radio" id="no" name="yes_no" value="no">
              <label for="dewey">no</label>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Add Book"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </i>Library
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button onclick="openNav()" class="add-book">
    <i class="fa fa-plus plus-sign"></i>
    Add book</button>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="main">
</div>
<script src="./index.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/30a34909cc.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned the `click` event at loading time to all existing buttons with `class=="delete"`. This will naturally not include the ones you might add dynamically at a later stage.

If you want *all* ".delete" buttons to have the click-event attached to them you need to do a "delegated event attachment" (**edited**, removes myLibrary element too now):

```
// Add event listener to all current and future deleteButtons
document.querySelector('.main').onclick=ev=>{
 let el= ev.target.classList.contains('fa-trash')? ev.target.parentElement : ev.target.classList.contains('delete') ? ev.target : false;
 if (el) {
   let card=el.parentElement.parentElement; // book-card DOM element
   // remove myLibrary array-element here:
   myLibrary.splice( [...card.parentElement.children].indexOf(card) ,1);
   console.log(myLibrary)
   // remove card DOM element:
   card.remove()
 }
}
```

This will bind the click event handler to the `.main` div and will react only if the clicked element has a `class=='fa-trash'` or `class=='delete'`. In the first case it will "move up" one level (assign the parent element, i. e. the button to `el`), otherwise the clicked element *is* the button itself. If none of these classes are found, `el` becomes `false` and nothing happens. Otherwise the "Grandparent" of `el` is removed with `el.parentElement.parentElement.remove()' .

And *please* try and make your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a little *smaller* next time, as it no fun to handle this amount of code in a small Stackoverflow snippet window! A true MCVE will get you more and faster responses!

Below is a working snippet, check it out:

```js
//DOM
const bookForm = document.querySelector(".book-form");

// Calling a form when clicking on add book button
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
  console.log("dsafsa");
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}

// where the books will be saved...
let myLibrary = [
  {
    title: "Harry Potter - and the Philosopher's Stone",
    author: "J. K. Rowling",
    pages: 223,
    readStatus: "no",
  },
  {
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "J.R.R. Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
    readStatus: "yes",
  },
];

// book object
function Book(title, author, pages, readStatus) {
  (this.title = title),
    (this.author = author),
    (this.pages = pages),
    (this.readStatus = readStatus);
}

let i = "";
// render the book on page load...
function render() {
  const books = myLibrary;
  books.forEach((book) => {
    addNewBookUI(book);
  });
}
render();

document.querySelector(".book-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  // prevent actual submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // get values
  const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  const author = document.querySelector("#author").value;
  const pages = document.querySelector("#pages").value;
  const readStatus = document.querySelector('input[name="yes_no"]:checked')
    .value;
  // prevent empty fields ...

  if (title === "" || author === "" || pages === "0") {
    alert("Missing data");
  } else {
    const book = new Book(title, author, pages, readStatus);
    myLibrary.push(book);
    addNewBookUI(book);
    clearFormFields()
  }
});

function addNewBookUI(book) {
  if (book.readStatus === "yes") {
    i = "checked";
  } else {
    i = "";
  }
  const main = document.querySelector(".main");
  const bookCard = document.createElement("div");
  bookCard.classList.add("book-card");
  bookCard.innerHTML = `<div class="delete_button"><button class="delete btn"><i class="fa fa-trash">
        </i></button></div><div class="title">${book.title}</div><div class="author">${book.author}
        </div><div class="pages">${book.pages}</div><div class="read_status">Read: <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="readstatus" value="yes" ${i}> 
        </div>`;
  main.appendChild(bookCard);
}

// clear form fields after submit 
function clearFormFields() {
  const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
  myForm.reset();
}

// Add event listener to all deleteButton 
document.querySelector('.main').onclick=ev=>{
 let el= ev.target.classList.contains('fa-trash')? ev.target.parentElement : ev.target.classList.contains('delete') ? ev.target : false;
 if (el) {
   let card=el.parentElement.parentElement;
   myLibrary.splice( [...card.parentElement.children].indexOf(card) ,1);
   console.log(myLibrary)
   card.remove()
 }
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { 
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
    
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:#155999;
    border-bottom: #172f4f solid 10px;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
}


header button {
    background-color: #183153;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.plus-sign {
    padding-right: 7px;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #183153;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
}



.book-card {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 1000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #155999;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    border: #172f4f solid 8px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    box-shadow: 10px 4px 22px -5px rgba(21,89,153,1);
}


.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(21,89,153);
  background-color: rgba(21,89,153,0.7);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #c3c6d1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
} 

.book-card div {
    margin-top:15px;
}

 /* Style buttons */
 .btn {
    background-color: #ffd43b; /* Blue background */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    color: red; /* White text */
    padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
    font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
    cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute; 
    top:-20px; 
    right:-15px;

  }
  
  /* Darker background on mouse-over */
  .btn:hover {
    background-color: #183153;
    
  } 

  .delete_button {
     
      top:0;
      right:0;
      
  }

  form div {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .radiobutton {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .form-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
.form-flex input {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px
}

.form-flex input::placeholder {
  text-align: center;

}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #183153;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.radiobutton p {
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;  
}

.flexbuttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}

input[type="text"]
{
    font-size:24px;
    text-align: center;
}
JS:

//DOM
const bookForm = document.querySelector(".book-form");
```

```html
<!-- The overlay -->
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    
        <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        
        <!-- Overlay content -->
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <form  id="myForm" class="book-form">
                <div class="form-flex">
                    <label for="title">Book name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Book name...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-flex">
                    <label for="author">Book author:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Book author...">
                </div >
                <div class="form-flex">
                    <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="0" name="pages">
        
                </div>
        
                <div class="radiobutton">
                    <p>Have you read a book?</p>
                    <div class="flexbuttons">
                        <div><p><input type="radio" id="huey" name="yes_no" value="yes" checked>
                            <label for="huey">yes</label></p>
                           
                        </div>
                        
                        <div><p><input type="radio" id="no" name="yes_no" value="no">
                            <label for="dewey">no</label></p>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
        
                <div><input type="submit" value="Add Book"></div>
        
            </form>
        </div>
            
        
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
  
  </div>
    
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </i>Library</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            
            <button onclick="openNav()" class="add-book">
                <i class="fa fa-plus plus-sign"></i>
                Add book</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class="main">
        
        
    </div>

    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/30a34909cc.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, you might wanna know how would I delete it also from the array myLibrary also?

Comment: I added the removal of the corresponding `myLibrary` element into the delete-button event handler function, please check again.